# How can I get my code to recognize when another a file has been changed as it is running?

Tags: java, file, methods, io, printwriter

I have a method in one file, XFunction.java, that rewrites another class in another file, NDrive.java, then calls the rewritten method from the NDrive class. The problem is, when the method is called, my code still seems to think the method is what it was before it was rewritten. In fact, even if ndrive.delete() returns true and ndrive.exists() returns false, my code STILL reads the old method (and the file NDrive.java is still there). Does my approach not make any sense? Is it fundamentally flawed, or can I fix it?

Here's the method below.

```
    private double evaluate(String exp) {

    File ndrive = new File("NDrive.java");
    PrintWriter write = null;
    Scanner scan = null;

    try {

        scan = new Scanner(ndrive);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

        System.out.println("File not found");

    }

    int lineCount = 0;
    String contents = "";
    if (scan != null) {
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            lineCount++;
            if (lineCount == 9) {
                contents += "        double y = " + exp + ";\n";
            } else {
                contents += line + "\n";
            }
        }

        
        try {
            write = new PrintWriter(ndrive);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.out.println("File not found for writer");
        }

        write.print(contents);
        System.out.print(contents);

        write.close();
        scan.close();


    }

    return NDrive.returnY();
}
```

The line NDrive.returnY() should return a different output since the body (contents) of that method in Ndrive.java was changed. But it doesn't. Unless the body of returnY() is "changed" to what it already is (is unchanged) which happens after I run the program again without changing the input exp, because the file NDrive.java already contains the new line.

Can anyone help? I've been looking at this for a really, really long time.

Comment: Java doesn't work that way. Source files (`.java`) need to be compiled to `.class` files, so runtime changes to your source files are not going to work.

Comment: Step back a little: `I have a method in one file, XFunction.java, that rewrites another class in another file, NDrive.java, then calls the rewritten method from the NDrive class.`. Why are you trying to do this? Is it for the sake of one or two methods in that class that need to be a little different? Perhaps you can just create **overloaded** methods in your class to accommodate the required differences.

Comment: Can you explain why you "need" to edit a java class file at runtime? A `.java` file is uncompiled and is not what your code is running (the IDE compiles them for you). There is likely a better way to achieve what you want. Having said that, you "could" bundle a compiler with your app and update the `.java` file then compile it on the fly then load it like an external library before attempting to call the methods... But that could open up a whole world of pain depending on a number of factors like how interconnected your classes are, what source files they depend upon, version mismatches etc.

Comment: @sorifiend, I was trying to find a way to get from a math function given as a string, along with an input, to its output; i.e "(2 * x + Math.pow(6.7, x)) / Math.pow(x, 3)" -> "(2 * (6.0) + Math.pow(6.7, (6.0))) / Math.pow((6.0), 3)" -> 418.844... I wanted it to work for any such function, not just one or two

Comment: @DevilsHnd See my reply to sorifiend - I wanted to go from any math function given as a string to an output, for any input

Comment: Don't edit the source, instead pass the string into the method that does the calculation and parse it accordingly. If you need to parse an entire string then use one of the many math parser libraries, or implement one yourself. The string itself could be loaded from a text file on the fly or from user input via a scanner or a popup prompt.